# MatLab scatter plot

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter

I am trying to generate a scatter plot within a current figure that has a gradient color. My gradient color works when I run the scatter plot in its own figure. however, when I add the scatter plot to the current figure it resets the color to a consistent color. Any ideas on why this would happen?

Comment: Did you try using `hold on`?  Also, showing us the code you wrote to illustrate your point would be nice.  We don't know how exactly you wrote the code, and so showing us will prevent us from guessing what you're after and seeing for ourselves what you're really after.

Comment: If you post some code we can get a better idea where things are going wrong.

Comment: I agree with @rayryeng. Since no one can really answer your question at the moment, I vote to close the question until you substantiate it with your current code and a better description. If you improve the question I'll remove the motion to close.